# Shell application in Vim window

Tags: vim, shell, console, interactive

I'm searching a way to start console application in vim window.
So I could open python & php interactive shell in it. It would be very handy.

I want something like

```
:10 sp !python
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try the [conque shell plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2771). Sounds like exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks that's it. Just wondering is there native way to set split window height/width?

Answer (score 3):

Bram Moolenaar writes:

**Executing shell commands in a window**

> There have been questions for the
>   possibility to execute a shell in a
>   window inside Vim.  The answer: you
>   can't!  Including this would add a lot
>   of code to Vim, which is a good reason
>   not to do this.  After all, Vim is an
>   editor, it is not supposed to do
>   non-editing tasks.  However, to get
>   something like this, you might try
>   splitting your terminal screen or
>   display window with the "splitvt"
>   program.  You can probably find it on
>   some ftp server.  The person that
>   knows more about this is Sam Lantinga
>   [slouken@cs.ucdavis.edu]. An
>   alternative is the "window" command,
>   found on BSD Unix systems, which
>   supports multiple overlapped windows. 
>   Or the "screen" program, found at
>   [www.uni-erlangen.de](http://www.uni-erlangen.de/), which supports a
>   stack of windows.

From Vim:

[`:help shell-window`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/tips.html#shell-window)